# How can i convert this sfdisk script invocation in a sequence of commands

Tags: bash, shell, partitioning, partition

I came across this sfdisk invocation

```
sfdisk {device} <<EOF
label: dos
unit: sectors
4MiB,252MiB,
256MiB,,
EOF
```

how can i convert this "script' in a sequence of sfdisk invocation? i mean something like

```
sfdisk ...
sfdisk ...
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: check if your version of `sfdisk` supports processing options on the cmd-line. `sfdisk --help` may error out with an unhelpul error message, or it may give you something you can work with. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to run a sequence of commands in a bash script, the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line) is good.  ie-

```
A; B    # Run A and then B, regardless of success of A
A && B  # Run B if and only if A succeeded
A || B  # Run B if and only if A failed
A &     # Run A in background.
```

If your question is more about generating scripts using the`sfdisk` utility in general, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/332252/how-to-create-and-format-a-partition-using-a-bash-script/1132834) has a good answer that explains how to do that. ie-

```
To generate an example script, get the setup of one of your disks:

sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.sfdisk
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the following description of the device layout content to a file[example : sda.dump] and provide that as input .

```
label: dos
unit: sectors
4MiB,252MiB,
256MiB,,

Example : 
sfdisk {device} < sda.dump
```